# simple PHP math = height

Tags: php, math

I'm kind of stuck with this, it SHOULD be very simple, but my brain can't wrap around it (it's Friday... lol)

I've got a thermometer, representing $1,000,000 max. it's 375px tall.

I'm running a DB Query to grab amounts from user submissions (between $1 and $200).

At that math, it's $2,666.66 per pixel to move it up 1 pixel ---

`retrieve_amount();` is my DB function that grabs all the amounts - that's simple.

```
$fill_query = retrieve_amount();
$fill = 0;
$total = 0;

while($fill_query->is_valid() ) : $fill_query->amount();
    $amount = get_valid_amount($input, 'amount');
    $total = $total + $amount;
endwhile;

$finaltotal = $total; // THIS is the line that grabs the final total from above. Should work?
$fillheight = $SOMETHING +/-* $SOMETHING; // this is the line that i'm less sure of how to get my result
```

It may be that I'm just not great with math, but my questions are

```
$finaltotal = $total
```

should work to receive the total amount retrieved from the DB Query, correct?

And more importantly, how do I translate that to the pixels that I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$maxPixels = 375;
$maxAmount = 1000000;
$currentAmount = 1234567;

$currentPixels = round(($currentAmount / $maxAmount) * $maxPixels);
```

It's basically just like calculating percentages. Except, instead of 100%, your max is now 375 pixels.

Comment: I like it, very clean, simple and efficient.

Comment: Well thank you! I love these types of questions. Hopefully it helps OP.

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm and cleaner than I thought :) I'll accept it when it allows :)